# What is projective duality from modern point of view ? (correspondence ? Fourier on D-mod ? Aut of D(Coh) ?)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Consider vector space $V$ and its dual $V^*$ then to any line subspace  in $V$ one can correspond its kernel in $V^*$ which is hyperplane. 
[Projective duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)) states that this correspondence satisfies many remarkable properties.

**Question** Is there some modern point of view on projective duality ? 
Does it act somehow on submanifolds of $P(V)$ ? Sending to some submanifolds of $P(V^ * )$  ?

Something like Fourier-Mukai transform or whatever ?

Fourier transform sends $D$-modules on $V$ to $D$-modules on $V^ *$ may it is somehow related ?

**PS**

One motivation comes from the [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107912/what-are-natural-automorphisms-of-set-of-subsets-how-to-constructify-andreas).

Also  I have the following example for $\mathbb{C}^3$

- the affine lines $(x,y, *)$ are mapped to points  $(x,y, 0 )$
- the points $(0, 0, z)$ are mapped to 2-dimensional subspaces $(*, *,
     z)$.

Can one put this in some framework of "projective duality"?

There are papers by A. Kuznetsov e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507292 "Homological Projective Duality"  it might be the answer, but at the moment I am not enough familiar to be sure that it is what I need.

Comment: «Does it act on submanifolds?» There is a classical theory of duality for subvarieties of projective space: for example, search for *dual curve*. 

Comment: There is quite a lot on projective duality in Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsky, Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional determinants.